# How to structure data in specified format?

Tags: java, collections

Somewhere in the project I need to structure data using Java in the format like
Syntax:

```
{String: [(int, int),(int, int),...]};
```

Example:

```
{"some expression": [(1, 20), (2,15),...]};
```

I tried using Maps collection. Somehow, I am able to format outer structure as
Map but I getting trouble to format data inside arraylist.

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList> expressionRanges = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();
```

How do I get structure specified as in above example using Java?

Comment: There are many ways to represent this data structure. You need to be more specific, how will you use it?

Comment: @user1803551 could you please mention on of the methods?

Comment: Yes, but you need to show how the data structure will be used, that is how its data is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do it in any one of the following ways:

> Using Map with String as **Key** and 2D Integer Array as **Value**:

```
// Declare the Map
Map<String, int[][]> expressionRanges = new HashMap<>();

// Declare the 2D Integer Arrays and fill them...
int[][] a = {{1, 20}, {2,15}, {3,30}};
int[][] b = {{6, 5}, {7,10}, {8,15}, {9,20},{10,25}};

// Add Integer Arrays to Map as values 
expressionRanges.put("Some Expression", a);
expressionRanges.put("Other Expression", b);

// Get 2D Integer Array from Map based on supplied Key string
int[][] tmp = expressionRanges.get("Other Expression");
// Display the contents of the 2D Integer Array
for (int i = 0;i < tmp.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tmp[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(tmp[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If run it displays the following in Console window:

```
6     5 
7     10    
8     15    
9     20    
10    25
```

> Using Map with String as **Key** and 2D ArrayList as **Value**:

```
// Declare the Map
Map<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> expressionRanges = new HashMap<>();

// Declare the 2D ArrayLists of Integer Type and fill them...
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> b1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
        b1.add(1); 
        b1.add(20); 
        a1.add(b1); 
    ArrayList<Integer> b2 = new ArrayList<>(); 
        b2.add(2); 
        b2.add(15); 
        a1.add(b2); 
    ArrayList<Integer> b3 = new ArrayList<>(); 
        b3.add(3); 
        b3.add(30); 
        a1.add(b3); 

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>a2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> b4 = new ArrayList<>(); 
        b4.add(6); 
        b4.add(5); 
        a2.add(b4); 
    ArrayList<Integer> b5 = new ArrayList<>(); 
        b5.add(7); 
        b5.add(10); 
        a2.add(b5);  
    ArrayList<Integer> b6 = new ArrayList<>(); 
        b6.add(8); 
        b6.add(15); 
        a2.add(b6); 
    ArrayList<Integer> b7 = new ArrayList<>(); 
        b7.add(9); 
        b7.add(20); 
        a2.add(b7); 
    ArrayList<Integer> b8 = new ArrayList<>(); 
        b8.add(10); 
        b8.add(25); 
        a2.add(b8); 

// Add ArrayLists to Map as values            
expressionRanges.put("Some Expression", a1);
expressionRanges.put("Other Expression", a2);                    

// Get 2D ArrayList from Map based on supplied Key string
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> values =  expressionRanges.get("Other Expression");
// Display the contents of the 2D ArrayList
for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < values.get(i).size(); j++){
        System.out.print(values.get(i).get(j) + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If run it displays the following in Console window:

```
6     5 
7     10    
8     15    
9     20    
10    25
```

Comment: Though both ways seems to work but those values which are stored inside 2-dimensional array has significant meaning in my case i.e they are not just numbers. So, sometime I may need to retrieve single index too and if I used 2D array I always have to use 2 loops even if I want to access single index. Is there any other optimal solution?